# Which assembly is used by Linux Kernel? Is it really NASM?

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm

I'm reading https://0xax.gitbooks.io/linux-insides/content/Booting/linux-bootstrap-1.html and it reads some assembly like

```
    .section ".reset", "ax", %progbits
    .code16
.globl    _start
_start:
    .byte  0xe9
    .int   _start16bit - ( . + 2 )
    ...
```

There's a line where he compiles like this

```
nasm -f bin boot.nasm && qemu-system-x86_64 boot
```

So I thougth it was NASM assembly for linux. I went and found https://asmtutor.com/# which says it uses NASM assembly for linux. However, it's not the same thing. Just to name a few: linux kernel uses `.section` instead of `SECTION`, `.globl` instead of `global` and I don't recognize what `.byte`, `.int`, etc does.

So which assembly does linux use and where can I learn it?

Comment: The kernel uses gnu assembler. You can of course use nasm or various other assemblers on linux if you like.

Comment: Note that each assembler comes with its own syntax.

Answer (score 7):

The Linux kernel uses the GAS assembler(GNU Assembler) which is part of GCC. You can find reference documentation on it [here](https://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/as_1.html).

You can find a pretty thorough introduction to GAS [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.32.4503&rep=rep1&type=pdf) provided that you already have a basic understanding of assembly in general.

As for `.byte` and `.int`, `.byte` places 1 or more 1 byte values that follow it into memory at the current assembler address, and `.int` does the same but for 32 bit integers instead of bytes.